# Write coordinates of array of values in multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
list = [[0, 5], [0, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4], [1, 7], [0, 1]]
```

Each element refers to a point with coordinates listed as two arrays:

```
Lon = [2.0,3.0,5.0,2.0,6.0,1.0,3.0,4.0]
Lat = [4.0,6.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,1.0,7.0]
```

I am trying to create an array that is in the following format:

```
[[Lon_0,Lat_0],[Lon_5,Lat_5]]
[[Lon_0,Lat_0],[Lon_3,Lat_3],[Lon_6,Lat_6]]
...
```

I tried the zip function but something is missing and I don't know how to move forward:

```
for m in list:
    for n in m:
        Coord = zip((Lon[n], Lat[n]))
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You don't need a for loop, just `zip(Lon, Lat)` and you're good.

Comment: just try `zip(Lon, Lat)`. To turn it into a list use: `list(zip(Lon, Lat))`.

Comment: Oh and something to note is, that `zip` will turn the "inner" list into a tuple. eg: `[(Lon_0, Lat_0), (...), ... ]`.

Comment: Also, consider renaming your "list" from `list` to something else, say `lst`. By naming a variable `list` you override the `list` constructor. So, for example, @pask's previous suggestion will not work even though it should.

Comment: But the zip function is not subscriptable, how do I call the zipped coordinate of each point as in the list?

Comment: This is beacause `zip` returns an iterable. You need to convert it to a list as I mentioned in my former comment. But as Yakym pointed out you need to rename your list otherwise it shadows the builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through each index inside each element of your list and rebuild an entry with the `Lon, Lat` values.

Here is the code:

```
# Sample data
list = [[0, 5], [0, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4], [1, 7], [0, 1]]
Lon = [2.0,3.0,5.0,2.0,6.0,1.0,3.0,4.0]
Lat = [4.0,6.0,5.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,1.0,7.0]

# Construct result list
result = []                                                                                                                          
for entry in list:
    elem = []
    for index in entry:
        elem.append([Lon[index], Lat[index]])
    result.append(elem)

# Sample output
print(result)
[[[2.0, 4.0], [1.0, 2.0]], 
 [[2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 1.0]], 
 [[3.0, 6.0], [5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 4.0]], 
 [[3.0, 6.0], [4.0, 7.0]], 
 [[2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 6.0]]]
```

In a more "pythonic" way you can use a single-line command (which might be harder to understand but does the exact same thing):

```
result = [[[Lon[index], Lat[index]] for index in entry] for entry in list]
```

Comment: @mrcbrbr Glad to hear it. Please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you need something like this:

```
[[[Lon[i], Lat[i]] for i in sub] for sub in mylist]
#[[[2.0, 4.0], [1.0, 2.0]],
# [[2.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 1.0]],
# [[3.0, 6.0], [5.0, 5.0], [6.0, 4.0]],
# [[3.0, 6.0], [4.0, 7.0]],
# [[2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 6.0]]]
```